# Rotating (circular shifting) a binary number - what is the rotational distance between the minimum and maximum?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, binary

I started continuing thoughts from [What exactly happens, when I do a bit rotation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/what-exactly-happens-when-i-do-a-bit-rotation).
Let us take a binary number $B$ of length $L$ with $N$ ones, for example $L=8$, $N=5$ and $B=10110101=181$, the minimum (obtainable by rotating $B$) is $B_{min}=01011011=91$ and the maximum is $B_{max}=11011010=218$. The (left-)rotational distance $d(B_{min},L)=r$ is the required amount of left rotates from the minimum to the maximum. In this example $d(B_{min},L)=r=3$, since we obtain the maximum $11011010$ by three left rotates ($r=3$) of the minimum $01011011$.

What is the general formula of calculating the rotational distance $d(B_{min},L)$?

What we know so far is that $B_{max}=(B_{min}\cdot2^r)\bmod{(2^L-1)}$ which means in our example $218=(91\cdot2^3)\bmod(255)$ and thus $r$ might be obtained by the discrete logarithm, which is not so manageable.

Hopefully there is way to calculate $r$ explicitely (avoiding trial-&-error).

Maybe we can show that $L\mid N\cdot r+1$

Comment: What have you tried? Why is this a question of interest? Seems like you just have to identify the maximum (resp min) based on the number of consecutive 1's that exist, and iterate from there.

Comment: I started continuing thoughts based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/what-exactly-happens-when-i-do-a-bit-rotation. I am looking for a formula that provides the rotational distance by one shot (like the one for rotations given behind the mentioned link), not an iterative function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order that the divisibility $L\mid N\cdot r+1$ is given, we must show that:

- $\gcd(B_{min},2^L-1)\mid B_{max}$
- $2^L-1\mid2^rB_{min}-B_{max}$

which leads us to the diophantine equation that must have an integer solution $a,b$:

$(2^L-1)\cdot b=2^{\frac{a\cdot L-1}{N}}\cdot B_{min}-B_{max}$

In our example $a=b=2$ provide a solution: $(2^8-1)\cdot b=2^{\frac{a\cdot 8-1}{5}}\cdot91-218$.